# google app engine flexible with docker 'site cannot be reached'

Tags: r, docker, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, plumber

I want to server R model using App Engine.
I am following this example [R with app engine](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/serverless-R-API-appengine), but stuck. I tried several methods but still have issues. Any guidance on this issue?

Please refer to my code
**app.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gcr.io/gcer-public/plumber-appengine
LABEL maintainer="mark"

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('plumber'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

WORKDIR /payload/
COPY [".", "./"]

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)"]
CMD ["schedule.R"]
```

**schedule.R**

```
#* @get /demoR
get_predict_length <- function(){

  dataset <- iris

  # create the model
  model <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = dataset)
  petal_width = "0.4"

  #petal_width = '0.4'
  # convert the input to a number
  petal_width <- as.numeric(petal_width)

  #create the prediction data frame
  prediction_data <- data.frame(Petal.Width=petal_width)

  # create the prediction
  predict(model,prediction_data)
}
```

I deploy using 'gcloud app deploy  and its successful. I get a link 'https://iris-custom-dot-my-project-name.appspot.com/'.

Final output in logs

Stackdriver logs show:

```
  Starting server to listen on port 8080
```

when I click on app engine version https://iris-custom-dot-my-project-name.appspot.com/' , I get below message:

> **This site can’t be reached**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Office network issue**

In my case the real issue was, my office network blocked port 8080, so when I connected from home or in office over mobile hotspot, it worked.

**In general follow below steps to resolve the issue.**

1) search google **'my public IP address"**

2)  Add your IP in firewall rules will resolve the issue.

either use gcloud commands

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/firewall-rules/create
or

using GCP UI ( you can use any priority number which has not been used already)

[image]